# How to use a classification model to choose the best one from three survival models?

Tags: classification, time-series

I have a survival data like this:

```
Sum    Days
 4      10
 5      12
 2      7
 3       8
```

Let's say this is a ink purchase history of one credit card. Sum means how many bottles of ink the credit card buys at that time. Days means how many days are before this credit card makes another purchase. So, the first two lines means this credit card buys 4 bottles of ink at first time. Then 10 days later, this card buys 5 bottles. So, I consider this to be a survival model. All the data except for the last line is the training set. The last line is the test set. The model trained by the training set is used to predict the value of Days of the last line given the value of Sum. In this example, I think the model is satisfying if the predicted value is 9 as 9 is pretty close to the real value 8.

I have like 1000 credit cards each with its own ink purchase history. I trained three survival models seperately: weibull, average and ctree. We can expect that one model performs better on these credit cards while the other is more suitable for other cards.

So, I want to use a classification method to identify which data (credit cards) suits which survival model more so that my system can automically decide which survival model will be used when a particular credit card data comes in.

However, it I take the purchase data as a time series, then in my data, this is very sparse. Thereforely it is probably not good for time series classification. So, what I want to ask is if ther is a classification model which can do this?